# jQuery selector wildcard-mapping unknown variable

Tags: jquery, selector, wildcard-mapping

**HTML**

```
<select id="edit-attributes-1"></select>
<select id="edit-attributes-2"></select>
<select id="edit-attributes-3"></select>
<select id="edit-attributes-4"></select>
```

This is generated by a cms and I cannot do anything

**JQUERY:**

```
 $('select[id^="edit-attributes-"][id!="edit-attributes-12"]').after('<span class="step stepdown step-'+$(this).attr('id')+'">+</span>');
```

so I created this, since trying jquery.ui.spinner is problematic on identifying elements.

**NOTE:**

```
$(this).attr('id') here results as unknown.
```

**Results**

```
<select id="edit-attributes-1"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**unknown**">+</span>
<select id="edit-attributes-2"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**unknown**">+</span>
<select id="edit-attributes-3"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**unknown**">+</span>
<select id="edit-attributes-4"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**unknown**">+</span>
```

As you can see the part of $(this).attr('id') is unknown.

**Desired results**

```
<select id="edit-attributes-1"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**edit-attributes-1**">+</span>
<select id="edit-attributes-2"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**edit-attributes-2**">+</span>
<select id="edit-attributes-3"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**edit-attributes-3**">+</span>
<select id="edit-attributes-4"></select>
   <span class="step stepdown step-**edit-attributes-4**">+</span>
```

I am not aware how can I achieved this kind of concept, or otherwise please present a best way how to simplify things.

Comment: Using this has to have a context.. Where are you calling this ??

Comment: Also better to use $('select[id^="edit-attributes-"]').not('[id="edit-attributes-12"]') as it is faster than $('select[id^="edit-attributes-"][id!="edit-attributes-12"]')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in your code doesn't refer to your selected elements, you can use `after`'s function:

```
$('select[id^="edit-attributes-"][id!="edit-attributes-12"]').after(function(ind){
   return '<span class="step stepdown step-'+ this.id +'">+</span>'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qjVHM/

Comment: in jsfiddle there's no function(**ind**) but here you have it.

Comment: That's the `index` of selected elements in jQuery collection, _optional_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 $('select[id^="edit-attributes-"][id!="edit-attributes-12"]').each(function () {
    var this_selection = $(this);
    var selection_id = this_selection.attr('id');
    this_selection.after('<span class="step stepdown step-' + selection_id + '"></span>');  
 });
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, your code is more readable, so happened im looking for a shorter one, but i'm not pretty sure which one is the best,

Comment: I try to make my code as readable as possible, but I was just showing you the thought process that goes into it. Short is better from a performance standpoint. I just wanted to make sure you knew what was happening.